# SAXParser not throwing exception when encountered with invalid character

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

If i put a utf8 character » inside and ansi xml file and try to parse it with SAXParser then it is parsed without any error. Why it is not throwing any exception?

sample xml file. Save it as ansi encoding. Chrome unable to open the file but saxparser parses it without error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <root date="2010-06-17">
 <product
    id="1 "
    label= « xyz"/>
 </root>
```

[w3c xml validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) is also unable to check this document.

Comment: There should be an error if the UTF-8 stream is corrupt. Concise complete code example?

Comment: "ANSI" as the name of a character encoding is very dated! I think Microsoft started using this name for iso-8859-1 in the 1980s because it was the only ANSI standard they had ever come across. And then of course, they produced their own proprietary variant, best referred to as CP1252.

Answer (score 0):

The document is likely still well formed.

I haven't checked all the ANSI character sets, but `»` (U+00BB) is present in Windows-1252. If you dump the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence `C2 BB` into a Windows-1252 encoded file it would still be a legal byte sequence for that encoding. *It would be treated as the character sequence `Â»` (U+00C2 U+00BB).*

Answer (score 0):

### » is the following:

- U+00BB: Unicode code point
- c2 bb : Encoded in UTF-8
- 00 bb : Encoded in UTF-16
- bb    : Encoded in 8859-1/Windows 1252

If you put "c2 bb" in a file that is being read as win-1252 it will come out `Â»`.  There is no error needed.